# Crash during erase from map

Tags: c++, c++11, crash, segmentation-fault, c++14

I have a crash as consequence of unexpected behaviour.. I want to ask how could I modify the code to defence against this crash what happened.

```
   void SubscManag::handleNotif(Notif notif)
    {
   
        std::cout << "Current subscribe size: " << subs_.size();
        std::map<int, SubscData>::iterator it;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
            it = subs_.begin();
        }
        for (;;)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
            if (it == subs_.end())
            {
                break;
            }
            if (it->second.hasToBeErased)
            {
                std::cout << "Erase id : " << it->first;
                it = subs_.erase(it);
                continue;
            }
            if (cond)
            {
                // ....
                ++it;
                continue;
            }
            // ....
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

Crash is at line  it = subs_.erase(it);
with this

```
 Erase id : 2
 Erase id : 3
 Erase id : 28473456
```

So probably      `Element with id : 28473456` does not exist or was corrupted but how could I defense against crash ?
Thank you.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I cannot reproduce it

Comment: If you can't reproduce it with the full code how do you expect us to with only part of the code? Please provide a [mre]. My complete guess would be that you have overlapping calls to `handleNotif` on multiple threads and one invalidates the iterator of the other

Comment: I'm just asking for an advice|idea how this part of code be made more safely.. it's clear that in subs_ was not inserted anyting with   28473456  id

Comment: Your first lock is "wrong", as `it` might be invalidated before entering the loop.

Comment: I am convinced that the cause of the crash is not in the code shown here.  This function is not thread-safe, however.  You release the lock on your `mutex_` while iterating over the container, allowing other threads to invalidate `it`.

Comment: @Kevin124155 yes.  **Don't**  release the lock on your `mutex_` while iterating over the container.

Comment: @Kevin124155 how many times do you acquire a lock in this function?  `subs_.size() + 1` times?  That's also how many times you release the lock.  You are locking and unlocking repeatedly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234035/discussion-between-kevin124155-and-drew-dormann).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do lock based concurrency.

Lock based concurrency doesn't compose.  Locally correct operations, when concatenated, generate garbage.

Here, the problem is your `it` is generated in one lock, then you unlock.  During that unlock, the `it` may or may not be valid.  Then you relock and presume `it` is still valid.

You'll either have to lock the entire period you are working on the map, then unlock it and forget almost everything you knew in the lock (no carrying iterators out), rewrite your code based on immutable data structures, or do something else even more radical.

```
{
  std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
  it = subs_.begin();
}
```

here you are locking, doing an operation, then ... unlocking the mutex at the end of the scope.

So `it` is an iterator into the map, and you aren't stopping other threads from editing the map while you hold it.  This could invalidate `it`.

The same thing happens in your `for(;;)` loop; you lock at the start of each iteration, and then unlock at the end.  The map element that `it` refers to could be deleted, invalidating your `it`, between one iteration and the next.

Here is a simple utility class:

```
template<class T>
struct mutex_guarded {
  template<class F>
  auto read(F&& f)const {
    auto l = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    return f(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  auto write(F&& f) {
    auto l = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
    return f(t);
  }
private:
  mutable std::mutex m;
  T t;
};
```

now, change your `std::map<int, SubscData>` to `mutex_guarded<std::map<int, SubscData>>`.

Next:

```
void SubscManag::handleNotif(Notif notif)
{
  subs_.write([&](auto& subs_) {
    std::cout << "Current subscribe size: " << subs_.size();
    auto it = subs_.begin();
    for (;;)
    {
        if (it == subs_.end())
        {
            break;
        }
        if (it->second.hasToBeErased)
        {
            std::cout << "Erase id : " << it->first;
            it = subs_.erase(it);
            continue;
        }
        if (cond)
        {
            // ....
            ++it;
            continue;
        }
        // ....
        ++it;
      }
  });
}
```

and you'll have the mutex locked while accessing `subs_`.

Note that accessing `subs_` through other methods remains dangerous.  Guarding individual method calls with a mutex is a bad plan.  Making "this object can be accessed from any thread" is a recipe for disaster in 999/1000 cases, often delayed, with the initial small case working, then it exploding in deadlocks and race conditions long after the code was written.

`mutex_guarded` isn't the best solution, but it is better than per-method locks.

Comment: Just put a call to `std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);` at the beginning of `handleNotif` (and remove the other two).